# Increase value instead of updating user_meta with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I'm using the following code to allow people to add infantry or vehicle to their profile

```
function after_submission($form) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $user->ID;

    $infantry =  $form[1];
    $vehicle =  $form[2];

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'infantry', $infantry);
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'vehicle', $vehicle);
```

My problem is that infantry & vehicle is getting updated, rather than increased.

Any suggestions?

Comment: may i know why did you remove my answer as accepted @Kevin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;

$infantry =  $form[1];
$vehicle =  $form[2];

$oldInfantry = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'infantry', true);
$oldVehicle = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'vehicle', true);

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'infantry', $infantry+$oldInfantry);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'vehicle', $vehicle+$oldVehicle);
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this :

```
$oldInfantry = $user->infantry;
$oldVehicle =  $user->vehicle;

$extraInfantry =  $form[1];
$extraVehicle =  $form[2];

$newInfantry = $oldInfantry + $extraInfantry ;
$newVehicle = $oldVehicle + $extraVehicle;

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'infantry', $newInfantry);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'vehicle', $newVehicle);
```

Comment: Both, Golden! Thanks a whole lot